# How to add Tags to Private API Gateways in AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-sam

I have created an API Gateway using AWS::Serverless::API in SAM and now I want to add Tags to Gateway in order to enforce security constraints on every Gateway with the same tag.

```
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: PrivateApi
    StageName: v1
    Tags:
      - Key: TagName
        Value: TagValue
    MethodSettings:
    ...
```

After looking at the documentation I have came up with the code above. As the documentation states it supports Tags in the way shown above but when I deploy I get the following error.

`samcli.commands.validate.lib.exceptions.InvalidSamDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('PrivateApi', "Type of property 'Tags' is invalid.")] ('PrivateApi', "Type of property 'Tags' is invalid.")`

Link to Documentation about Tags: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

I figured out that the documentation on the AWS::Serverless::API page, and the Tags page is slightly wrong when using SAM.

The proper way of denoting a Tag in SAM is the following.

```
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: PrivateApi
    StageName: v1
    Tags:
      TagName: TagValue
    MethodSettings:
    ...
```

This subtle difference makes SAM deploy properly. 
As a helpful aside, in the API Stage you can verify that the Tag has been deployed properly.